# What is the difference between Turning Undead and Automatically Turning Undead?

Tags: cleric, osr, swords-and-wizardry

The S&W Complete Rulebook, at page 42, states that you roll 2d10 and consult the Turning Undead table for the result. Then, interpretation is offered as so:

> If the number on the dice is equal to or greater than the number shown on the table, 2d6 creatures of the targeted type are turned and will depart, not returning for 3d6 rounds.
>
> If the table indicates “T,” 2d6 undead creatures of the targeted type
> are automatically turned and will depart for 3d6 rounds.

It makes no further reference to this. What's the difference between turning undead regularly and turning undead automatically?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Where the table has a number, your roll needs to meet or exceed that number to turn that type of undead. Where the table has a **T**, that type of undead are turned automatically regardless of what you rolled.

For example, a 4th-level cleric is facing a wight, a pair of ghouls, and a half-dozen zombies. The cleric makes a turning attempt. The zombies are automatically turned, but the ghouls and the wight require a roll, so the cleric's player rolls 2d10 and—bad luck—gets a 9. That's good enough to turn the ghouls, but not high enough to turn the wight. The ghouls and (rolling 2d6, the player gets a 7) all the zombies flee, and the wight advances undeterred.